# Sort using function on attribute found using attrgetter

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I'd like to sort a list `foo_list` using a function `foo_function` on an attribute `foo_attr` on each object in the list (same attribute for all objects). I've tried using the code below:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=foo_function(attrgetter('foo_attr')))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'operator.attrgetter' object has no attribute foo_attr
```

**Edit:** Updated to clarify. I copied sorting code, which used operator.attrgetter. Based on the answers it's clear that operator.attrgetter is not needed for my simple needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply additional functions instead of just obtaining the attribute, the shortest way is to use a lambda expression:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda x: foo_function(getattr(x, foo_attr)))
```

If, on the other hand, your attribute name is always the same (this isn't clear from the question), it would become:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda x: foo_function(x.foo_attr))
```

Comment: Won't do what the OP wants - since "foo_attr"  should obviously be dynamic.

Comment: @chepner: the question would not even make sense otherwise.  Anyway, this answer is fixed (and I fixed my voting on it accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

The `attrgetter` call returns you a callable, to which you should pass your original object in order to have your desired attribute returned:

```
>>> operator.attrgetter("upper")("")
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x7f86baa82508>
```

In your case you are passing this callable to `foo_function`, but there is no way `foo_function`  can get the original object where to apply `attrgetter` to startwith;

The most straightforward thing to do is to place a lambda, and explicitly 
retrieve the attribute on the expression, before calling `foo_function`:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda obj: foo_function(attrgetter(foo_attr)(obj)))
```

Actually, even more direct is to skip `attrgetter` altogether, and just use
the `getattr` builtin - this is most likely what you want:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda obj: foo_function(getattr(obj, foo_attr)))
```

And, if you want to actually go with attrgetter, it can be more efficient if you place it outside any loop - so it is defined just once and re-used a lot of times - if you ar enot doing this in a loop, there is no actual use for it, but harming your readability over `getattr`.

```
getter = operator.attrgetter(foo_attr)
for  list_ in my_lists:
    results.append(sorted(list_, key=lambda obj: foo_function(getter(obj)))
```

Comment: That's far from the most straightforward thing you can do. The whole point of `attrgetter` is to avoid a `lambda` in the first place. Once the `lambda` is necessary anyway (because Python doesn't have a function composition operator), you may as well just write the much simpler (and more efficient) `obj.foo_attr`.

Comment: @chepner: as I've stated clearly in the othr two answers: foo.foo_attr would only work if foo_attr were the literal attribute name, not a variable containing it.  (And it is so, given the code sample in the question itself)

Comment: Agreed. I think the question is vaguely worded, however, since the *error* message wouldn't also say `foo_attr`; it would have the value stored in `foo_attr`.

Comment: Sorry for sounding rude in some (most) of the comments- it happens when trying to get well documented answers and still wanting to keep  other's answers correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda foo: foo_function(foo.foo_attr))
```

That said, I'm not sure where this attrgetter comes into play. If it gets the foo_attr for you, then you can try using:

```
sorted(foo_list, key=lambda foo: foo_function(attrgetter(foo)))
```

Comment: `attrgetter(foo_attr)` is usually used to avoid having something like `key=lambda foo: foo.foo_attr`. Since the value is being passed to yet another function anyway (and Python doesn't have a nice syntax for function composition), `key=lambda foo: foo_function(foo.foo_attr)` is probably more readable.

Comment: Obviously "foo_attr" is an attribute name inside a variable, and the form foo.foo_attr won't work. If you (or @chepner") don't agree that foo_attr is in a variable, but is the literal attribute name, that should be addressed in the question, as its use without quotes in the question would be incorrect. (it would be `attrgetter("foo_attr")` and not `attrgetter(foo_attr)` as it is)

Comment: Obviously that wasn't obvious to me, @jsbueno, but thanks for pointing it out. If it were a variable holding a string with the attribute's name, why not use getattr()? I guess I was thrown by the 'attrgetter' part and might not have investigated the rest of the context to see what made the most sense.